# Mock methods of static member of testing class using mockito and powerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to mock methods of a static member of the testing class. It gives the expected output for one test case but if I try to mock the same method or other methods of that static member I do not get the expected output.

Here is an Example:

ClassToBeTested.java:

```
public class ClassToBeTested {
        static private memberObj = SomeClass.SomeMethod();

        public static void normalMethod1() {
            System.out.println(memberObj.someMethod1());
        }

        public static void normalMethod2() {
            System.out.println(memberObj.someMethod2());
        }

    }
```

TestClass.java:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassToBeTested.class, SomeClass.class})
public class TestClass {
    @Before
    public void init() {
        ClassOfMemberObj mockedMemberObject = Mockito.mock(ClassOfMemberObj.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SomeClass.class);

PowerMockito.when(SomeClass.someMethod()).thenReturn(mockedMemberObject);
    }
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        PowerMockito.when(mockedMemberObject.someMethod1()).thenReturn(21);
        ClassToBeTested.normalMethod1();
    }
    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
        PowerMockito.when(mockedMemberObject.someMethod1()).thenReturn(40);
        ClassToBeTested.normalMethod1();
    }
    @Test
    public void testMethod3() {
        PowerMockito.when(mockedMemberObject.someMethod2()).thenReturn(20);
        ClassToBeTested.normalMethod2();
    }
}
```

On running every test cases one by one, I got value on console as 21, 40 and 20 respectively. But if I run TestClass I get below values on console..

```
21
21
null
```

It seems like scope of Mocking methods of static member is just one test case. Is there any way to mock methods of static member from different test case?

Comment: Just for the record: you understand that whenever *static* breaks your ability to write *simple* unit tests, and you have to use PowerMock(ito) ... the better answer would be to not using static in such ways?!

Comment: I support @GhostCat's comment: What you have is [STUPID code](https://williamdurand.fr/2013/07/30/from-stupid-to-solid-code/) like most of us wrote in the beginning. You should learn from our mistakes and start writing SOLID code as soon as possible.

Comment: If you used *Spock*, the entire mock would be a one-liner.

Comment: @GhostCat, Thank you for your response. I am writing JUnit test cases for a project in a company and because of confidentiality policy, I could not share my original code and also I am not permitted to edit that project's code. Above code snippet represent just the situation I got while writing test cases. If I solve the above problem, I can easily solve my problem in the project.

Comment: It is fine that you provided a minimal example here. What I am telling you is that your production code shouldn't be reduced to such an example. As said: when *static* gets in your way of proper unit testing, then you are doing the wrong thing. But lets see if I can help with your actual question later today.